# Redirect /logout request to /api/logout webflux spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am trying to redirect default logout of spring (/logout) to some other endpoint(/api/exit). I am using reactive programming webflux. I got some answer and i found this:

```
@Bean
RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routerFunction() {
    return  route(GET("/"), req ->
            ServerResponse.temporaryRedirect(URI.create("/login"))
                    .build());
}
```

I am not getting which class i have to import for GET("/") method. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need `RequestPredicates.GET()` which comes from `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RequestPredicates`

So, the `import` statement will look like

`import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RequestPredicates;`

Alternatively, you can also use the following to create functional endpoints

```
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunctions;

RouterFunctions.route().GET().build()
```